How do the EU countries control artificial market prices?
Suppose various classes of people, e.g., whole-salers, retailers, middlemen, brokers, etc., sell the products or produce at much higher rates than the factory or farm sold them.
As a result, there is an artificial markup, and the end-users or end-consumers become the losers.
Do the EU governments control this? If so, how?

That's not "inflation". Inflation is the rise in prices over time. That is just normal "value added" profit. The wholesaler provides a service to the retail outlet, and gets to make a profit.  The retailer pays for the convenience of not having to deal directly with farmers or deal with import laws etc.  The retailer provides a service to the final customer, and get to take a profit.  Sure, you are free to own your own cow, but for most people the convenience of getting milk at the store easily outweighs the savings that could be made.

The word "artificial" is also probably not the best here either. One might argue that it's "artificial" [for authorities] to regulate prices and that monopolies (or cartels) "naturally" set higher prices. I'm not sure how to rewrite that bit without sounding biased one way or the other (towards regulation or laissez faire).

Perhaps "How do the EU countries control high markup in prices?" is a better title for this Q. FWTW, someone coined the term "greedflation" for this, but perhaps it's best to avoid such loaded neologisms.

Typically governments care more about sales under the supplier's price than mark-up.

@Relaxed: only for imports.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Do you mean they don't care about sales under the supplier's price for goods not imported? That is definitely not the case. Or do you mean they care more about those prices only in the case of imports? Don't think so either. Quite generally, they don't like one distributor with deep pockets trying to kill competitors by selling at a loss, only to be able to raise prices at will once the competitors have exited the market.

@Relaxed In some markets (especially agricultural products) there is a strong push against distributors pressuring the producers (farmers) into very low prices (sometimes below cost), only to keep a large margin for themselves. And of course they don't like cartels and other forms of collusion.

@jcaron That's one of the things I am referring to, yes.

Note that generally, prices are free, and are a function of supply and demand. Many products and services do not see their prices based on the cost, but on what customers are willing to pay (what added value it brings them).

@Relaxed but in that case the distributor is not selling under the supplier's price (the supplier may be selling under its own cost, though).

@jcaron I suspect IVFcomesfromthetip means they don't care about exports (but this does leave domestic production, which is a big issue in France as you know).

@jcaron Can be either and I was a bit sloppy with the terminology, my point being that governments care more about prices and mark-up (on the supplier's side) being too low, not too high, exactly for the reasons you detalied.

If the markup is excessive, this is called "price gouging". It can even happen at the original producer (they normally price things higher than their production costs, so they can make a profit), not just the middlemen.

"Suppose various classes of people, e.g., whole-salers, retailers, middlemen, brokers, etc., sell the products or produce at much higher rates than the factory or farm sold them." This is true 100% of the time. It isn't artificial. It is normal.

@IVFcomesfromthetip tell that to the various minimum price laws across the EU.

The first line of defence is having competition, so if one business increases its prices beyond what is reasonable, it would lose market share to other business who do not.
In that order, the EU can veto mergers and integrations in order to ensure that no business is in a position so dominant that there is no alternative to it.
Of course, despite what theorists of Capitalism like to say, business can find it more profitable to coordinate with their competition than to actually, er, compete. They may reach an agreement so that they get profits not by increasing their market share or reducing cost but by collectively increasing prices, becoming a cartel that controls a given market.
Those agreements are illegal and prosecuted at various levels by EU and government agencies. For example, Spain did uncover a cartel of car companies agreeing not to compete in prices, and did fine them heavily. Similarly, the EU did fine a cartel related to truck sales.
These actions are related not only to price fixing, but that can affect other agreements that limit competition.
One issue with those measures is that it might be difficult to prove. If several companies settle into a similar level of prices/margins, that is legal as long as it is not part of an agreed deal. So, it may investigate suspicious market activity but needs evidence (usually a whistleblower) of collusion.
So:

The gas station left of your home deciding that it will put the same prices that they see at the gas station right of your home is legal.
Both station owners meeting for lunch and agreeing not to lower the prices is illegal.
One of the owners trying to buy the other station is legal, but the economic authorities may ban the operation.


The gas station to your left rising prices in order to see what happens, and the gas station to the right seeing that and also rising prices is also not illegal. There can be de facto price cartels without ever having been any collusion, just by people figuring out that behaving a certain way is beneficial for everyone involved. This kind of price fixing is absurdly hard to combat.

Even Adam Smith, whom some might consider the first major theorist of capitalism, believed that "People of the same trade seldom meet together, even for merriment and diversion, but the conversation ends in a conspiracy against the public, or in some contrivance to raise prices." Such a cartel or trust is essentially another form of monopoly from an economic perspective, and while standard economic analysis does suggest a net deadweight loss to society as a whole from such practices, it definitely does not assert that the profits of the cartel are lower than under perfect competition.

@Polygnome Well, the theory if that it goes for long enough and prices are raised high enough, someone from outside the industry will enter the market with a better offer. Of course, this simplified version conveniently ignores entry barriers (either legal or because of the capital needed).

@SJuan76: Often, the entrenched competitor(s) have enough capital to drive the outsider out of business.  The entrenched competitor(s) will, of course, argue that the agressive price war (possibly operating at a loss) was merely normal competition.  Of course, such a reaction also makes it tougher for future competitors to acquire VC capital.

@Brian - Exactly. In highly competitive markets with a relatively low cost of entry, such as restaurants, most businesses will operate close to breaking even. McDonald's couldn't charge $50 for a burger even if Burger King also did, because every major city has dozens or hundreds of other places that sell burgers, and plenty of people could start their own. But with something like, say, GPUs, where there are only a handful of companies in the business and the entry barrier is billions of dollars, this cannot happen.

but by collectively increasing prices, becoming a cartel that controls a given market => this has never happened in history for a non-trivial duration of time, with the sole exception of government-enforced monopolies. I suggest editing it to confirm that this is a myth - or providing a single lasting example. Only goods without substitutes would count - so i.e. a cartel on bananas would not count if other types of fruit are easily available to buy instead. There's also the example of OPEC but even they failed to coordinate things for too long.

@JonathanReez: The Quinine Cartel lasted almost 40 years at a time time when quinine was the only effective medicine against malaria.

@JonathanReez a cartel doesn't have to be global. If there are 3 gas stations in a town in a cartel, they can raise prices to the break even point of "drive one town over to fill up".

@Caleth - From a certain (basically useless) perspective, no cartel can ever exist. If prices are raised above what a consumer is willing to pay, then the product will be substituted with non-consumption in the case of non-essential goods, or with theft in the case of truly essential ones like food and water. ...As I said, not a particularly useful perspective, but it is an extreme someone could go to in order to claim that cartels can never exist, if they keep moving the goalposts.

From Niamh Dunne, "Regulating prices in the European Union":

EU law interacts with and regulates price-setting on three distinct levels. First, via the competition
rules, it constrains the ability of individual undertakings to set prices in certain instances. Examples range from
a blanket proscription of price-fixing cartels, to more exceptional condemnation of excessive pricing by
dominant firms. Second, EU law limits the ability of Member States to regulate prices, particularly under the
free movement rules. [...] Third, and most
unusually, there is scope for direct implementation of price controls as a matter of EU law. A prominent
example is the Roaming Regulation, which capped and progressively reduced prices for mobile phone
customers who use their devices abroad.

So yeah, in addition the first issue, covered by SJuan76's answer, they sometimes regulated prices directly (3rd "level"). Another example of the last kind is the Interchange Fees Regulation for credit & debit cards, although this was less visible to consumers directly. Both of these

proceed on the assumption
that, absent EU-level regulation, disparate and potentially distortive national price controls were likely to
arise.

On the middle issue/level, the EU allows member states to regulate prices in some markets, e.g.

The electricity sector, where the continued presence of natural monopoly segments creates persistent
structural barriers to competition, provides a clear example. Here, although the ultimate objective is to secure ‘transparent market-based mechanisms for the supply and purchase of electricity,’
the liberalisation
framework acknowledges the continuing necessity for price supervision. The Third Electricity Directive
expressly permits Member States to impose public service obligations with respect to, inter alia, price.

Discussing how each member state does the latter is probably a long discussion. But the Electricity Directive actually mandates that some prices be monitored by national regulators:

The Directive also mandates regulatory approval of wholesale-level transmission and distribution
tariffs,
reflecting the potential for inefficient pricing practices upstream to create bottlenecks to retail
competition. This reflects the ‘essential facility’ nature of such infrastructure, a parallel to the realm of
antitrust,
thus recognising the extent to which unduly high input prices may have knock-on negative effects
downstream. Consistent with the logic of the permissive approach, however, the liberalisation framework
does not determine access prices; instead, this is delegated to national regulators, albeit acting within the
circumscribed EU supervisory framework.

(Emphasis in original.)
And sometimes it gets really complicated in juggling various priorities as in the case of the Transparency Directive for medication prices.
